# How to change a cookie from javascript to angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I can get a cookie as the following. I call this cookie in my module and pass it as a parameter.

How do I change the code to get a cookie so that its all in standard angularjs code?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         Cookie();
     });

     function getCookie(cname) {
         var name = cname + "=";
         var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
         for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
             var c = ca[i].trim();
             if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
         }
         return "";
     }

     function Cookie() {
         var cookie = getCookie('Id');

     }

     function Module($http) {
         var self = this;
         self.$http = $http;
         self.CookieID = getCookie('Id');

         self.test = function() {
             var params = {
                 testId: self.CookieID
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: methinks you need [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies)

Comment: yeah im not sure how to use it,since i already hv the id set in another page

Answer (score 3):

**Angular** [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies)

First include angular-cookies.js in your HTML:

```
<script src="angular.js">
<script src="angular-cookies.js">
```

Then load the module in your application by adding it as a dependent module:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);
```

Usage Example

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```

**jQuery**

Set Cookie

```
$.cookie("my_cookie", value);
```

Set Cookie with Expiration (in days) and Path

```
$.cookie("my_cookie", value, { expires: 1, path: '/' });
```

Remove Cookie

```
$.removeCookie("my_cookie");
```

Comment: i tired this,but nothing gets passed to my parameter

Comment: I have updated my answer with jQuery support as well.

Comment: i have to use angular js

Comment: i used local storage service instead [link](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)?

Secondly you could use [jQuery cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery) - if AngularJs cookie won't do for you.

Example:

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```